# What is the purpose of the number in script tag after file name?

Tags: html, script-tag

I am working on upgrading an old rails application.
In a public page, I have the following code:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-min.js?1327612345" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The file is named jquery-min.js. However, what is the purpose of `?1327612345`?

Comment: It's either a cache buster or versioning of the file. The true purpose only the author can tell you.